# apache poi 4.X, 5.X with net.sf.jxls.jxls-core causes java.lang.NoSuch MethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.cell.getCellType() error

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls-poi</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

pom.xml

```
InputStream is = null;
OutputStream os = null;
Workbook resultWorkbook = null;

try {
            String fileName = map.get("fileName").toString();
            String templateName = map.get("templateName").toString();
            Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>) map.get("data");

                String tempDirPath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/assets/template");
                File templateFile = new File(tempDirPath + File.separator + templateName);
                is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(templateFile));
                XLSTransformer transformer = new XLSTransformer();
                resultWorkbook = transformer.transformXLS(is, data);
                //autoSizeColumns(resultWorkbook);
                response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + 
  this.specialCharacterConversion(request, fileName) + ".xlsx");
                response.setContentType("application/x-msexcel");
                os = response.getOutputStream();
                resultWorkbook.write(os);
                os.flush();
 } catch(IOException | InvalidFormatException e) {
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }
```

resultWorkbook = transformer.transformXLS(is, data);
in this area, java.lang.NoSuch MethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.userModel.cell.getCellType() error occurs.

I want to use apache poi at least version 4.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

The projects `org.jxls` and `net.sf.jxls` are different projects. And `net.sf.jxls` seems to be dead since 2014. It only works using `apache poi 3.9`. So if later `apache poi`versions shall be used, you must using `org.jxls` only. There  `org.jxls` » `jxls-poi` » `2.11.0` will work using  `apache poi 4.1.2`.

But your code is for usage with `net.sf.jxls`. So this code also needs to be changed.

See http://jxls.sourceforge.net/getting_started.html for how to code for usage with `org.jxls`.